# HTML5 Video Player - video.js - Different behaviour at the end of video play on Chromium and Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

I am using video.js,

I am rendering video in two different browsers.

Chromium : Version 31.0.1650.63 Ubuntu 13.04 and

Mozilla Firefox : 26.0

I have given option of autoplay of video

HTML markup and Jq code is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("video").on("ended", function(){ 
      var vid = videojs($(this).attr("name"));
      vid.controlBar.hide();
      vid.bigPlayButton.show();
    });     
  $("video").on("pause", function()
    { 
       var vid = videojs($(this).attr("name"));
       vid.bigPlayButton.show(); 
    });  
  $("video").on("play", function(){  
       var vid = videojs($(this).attr("name"));
       vid.controlBar.show();
       vid.bigPlayButton.hide();
    });
 </script>
```

While video playing ends - firefox browser shows some spinner while chromium shows rectangular box to click to re play video.

[image: here is mark up of video tag]

[image]

[image]

Please tell why there is difference between behavior ?
How we can overcome this ?

Comment: I think its browser defaults.

Comment: It comes in to picture because of some error in FF - just now I studied somewhere, but want to overcome that if possible or else I will have to remove that spinner creating code :(

Comment: Have you tried using the videojs event handlers?

Comment: Nop.. I haven't done something like that..

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with the videojs events by doing something like:

```
var activePlayers = videojs.players;
$.each( activePlayers, function(key,value) { 
    value.on('ended', function() {
        this.controlBar.hide();
        this.bigPlayButton.show();
        this.loadingSpinner.hide();
    });
});
```

This is rather quick and may a bit of tweaking mainly with using `$.each` vs a `for( x in obj)` and if jquery wraps `value` in a jquery object.

Aside: I know using anonymous functions inside loops is frowned upon, but this is to give you the idea.

Comment: I added a line to hide the loading spinner.  This is kind of hackish, but should work.

Comment: Not working still.. I have added `this.loadingSpinner.hide();` in all the 3 function I have mentioned in question, I think I will have to find JS code which adds that div & will comment that JS code itself